# If $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent, prove $\sum \frac{a_{n}}n$ is also convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum $$a_{n}$ is convergent, prove  $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ is also convergent.

I would say that $a_{n}\geq \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ so being $a_{n}$ convergent, $\frac{a_n}{n}$ also has to be convergent.

However, I think it is not enough...

Comment: It is not: if $a_n=-1$, then $-1>-1/n$ is not true for $n>1$.  If you know further that $a_n\geq 0$ for every $n$, then you can use Direct Comparison though

Comment: It is sufficient if $a_n$ is a series with nonnegative terms.

Comment: An almost direct comparison is also possible if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely (a strengthening of "converges with only positive terms").